# Spark output parquet issue

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, parquet, amazon-athena, presto

I have Spark Streaming application (v 2.4.0) which outputs parquet format data on minute basis. 
For some random files I'm getting issue when trying to read them with parquet-tools or Amazon Athena.

```
Required field 'uncompressed_page_size' was not found in serialized data!
```

This is how output part implemented.

```
ds.foreachRDD { rdd =>
    val filteredRDD = rdd.filter(_.isDefined).map(a => a.get)
    if (!filteredRDD.isEmpty()) {
        val spark = SparkSession.builder.config(rdd.sparkContext.getConf).getOrCreate()
        import spark.implicits._

        val now = utcNow()
        val location = s"${appConfig.output}" +
            s"/${datef(now, "yyyyMM")}" +
            s"/${datef(now, "yyyyMMdd")}" +
            s"/${datef(now, "yyyyMMddHH")}" +
            s"/${appConfig.exchange}${datef(now, "yyyyMMddHHmmss")}"
        filteredRDD.toDF().write.parquet(location)
    }
}
```

Any idea what is the reason of spark not writing Required header fields?

Comment: did you figure out what the issue was here?